# row number broken when its used with CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

This is my query the SQL inside CTE works fine and all I want to get first 20 rows for each city name:

```
WITH taniCte
AS (
    SELECT sl.Adi AS [CityName],
        mt.ICD10Kodu AS [Tanı],
        count(mt.ICD10Kodu) AS sayi,
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY sl.Adi
            )
    FROM Muayene.Muayene mm WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN Muayene.Tani mt WITH (NOLOCK) ON mm.ID = mt.MuayeneId
    INNER JOIN Ortak.Kurum ok WITH (NOLOCK) ON mm.CreatedKurumKodu = ok.KurumKodu
    INNER JOIN Skrs.Il sl WITH (NOLOCK) ON ok.IlKodu = sl.Kodu
    GROUP BY sl.Adi,
        mt.ICD10Kodu
    ) --order by [CityName], sayi desc // commentewhen its moved inside cte
SELECT [CityName],
    [Tanı],
    sayi,
    RowNum
FROM taniCte
WHERE RowNum <= 20
ORDER BY [CityName],
    sayi DESC
```

Eventhough main query works fine the query above returns wrong rows..

I couldn't find any solution on internet

Comment: The query looks fine. Could you please provide sample data and expected results?

Comment: What is wrong? What is the intent of RowNum <=20? Do you need 20 different cities ordered by  ICD10Kodu's count? Your data inside cte is at the level of city name and ICD10Kodu  which means that you may get all 20 rows for same city

Comment: Why are you using `nolock`? You know what that does, right?

Comment: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need 20 rows per city then your row_number OVER clause in cte should be

```
with taniCte as
(
  select sl.Adi as [CityName]
       , mt.ICD10Kodu as [Tanı]
       , count(mt.ICD10Kodu) as sayi
       , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(partition By sl.Adi order by count(mt.ICD10Kodu)) -- this change in over clause
  from Muayene.Muayene mm with(nolock)
       join Muayene.Tani mt with(nolock) on mm.ID = mt.MuayeneId
       join Ortak.Kurum ok with(nolock) on mm.CreatedKurumKodu = ok.KurumKodu
       join Skrs.Il sl with(nolock) on ok.IlKodu = sl.Kodu
   group by sl.Adi, mt.ICD10Kodu 
   --order by [CityName], sayi desc // commentewhen its moved inside cte
)
select [CityName], [Tanı],sayi, RowNum 
from taniCte 
where RowNum <= 20 
order by [CityName], sayi desc
```

Comment: Man, god bless you and your family and anything in the world you love. Thanks!